# Front Page Not Updating

Tags: bug

Not sure if anyone else is noticing this but I am not longer getting notifications of new/updated questions on the front page of the site anymore. Other Stack Exchange sites that I have open in different tabs are still showing the X number of new posts notice in the tab and the page itself but I am not seeing this on Board Games. Now I am having to manually refresh the page to see if there are any new posts.

Comment: Just tested it, it's still working for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuHbA.png

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for the response. Makes me wonder why it works for some Stack Exchange sites for me but not others. I just had to refresh to see recent changes and no indication of any changes beforehand

Comment: I think I am also experiencing this. I don't think I have seen that notification banner recently.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Interesting, seems this isn't just a bug on my side and wonder what is different between us and Glorfindel

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's reporting a problem that can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: @doppelgreener Maybe you can no longer reproduce it but that doesn't mean it isn't happening to others still. This has not been solved for me and I don't see that as a reason to close the question.

Comment: I see, OK, my mistake. I've withdrawn my vote to close.

Comment: @JoeW Is it working now?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov As of Monday night it was still not updating but I am currently traveling and won't be able to check again until next week.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Got back and the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in SE code around ignored tags and has to do with the setting to hide them versus graying the question out. I was changed it from hiding (not sure how that got set that way as I had no ignored tags) to graying them out. After that change it started showing updates as expected.

This was found after I asked the question on Meta Stack Exchange and a helpful user was able to find the bug and explain it. More information can be found in the question and answer on Meta Stack Exchange

[Front Page Not Updating For All Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386009/front-page-not-updating-for-all-site/386110#386110)